# grep command exit code for unmatched patterns

Tags: shell, grep, exit-code

i have written a shell scripts which runs `crontab - l` command

To make it more easy to use i have also given the user an ability to pass a command line argument to the script which will act like a pattern input for the grep command, so that the user can filter out all the stuffs which he/she doesn't need to see.

here's the script:-

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
  3         echo -e "No Argument passed:- Showing default crontab\n"
  4         command=$(crontab -l 2>&1)
  5         echo "$command"
  6 else
  7         rc=$?
  8         command=$(crontab -l | grep -- "$1" 2>&1)
  9         echo "$command"
 10         if [[ $rc != 0 ]] ; then
 11                 echo -e "grep command on crontab -l was not successful"
 12         fi
 13 fi
```

this is how i run it

```
$ ./DisplayCrontab.sh
```

Now if i don't pass any command line argument it'll show me the complete crontab

If i pass any garbage pattern which doesn't exists in the crontab it'll show me the following message :-

```
 grep command on crontab -l was not successful
```

But even if i pass a pattern which does exist in a couple of lines in crontab, i'm getting this kind of output:-

```
#matching lines
#matching lines
#matching lines

grep command on crontab -l was not successful
```

Why am i getting grep command not successful at the bottom?, how can i get rid of it?

Is there anything wrong with the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're capturing the exit code before the execution, should be:

```
command=$(crontab -l | grep -- "$1" 2>&1)
rc=$?
```

To test this code use numeric operators:

```
[[ $rc -ne 0 ]]
```

Grep man:

> Normally,  the  exit  status  is  0  if  selected  lines are found and
>   1 otherwise.  But the exit status is 2 if an error occurred

Comment: oh this whole time i was thinking when i do `echo "$command"` then only my command will be executed, ahh still have alot to learn.
thank you :)